# How to set the debug mode path on QtCreator?

Tags: c++, debugging, qt5, qt-creator, qmake

In QtCreator we can have a debug build and a release build configuration. And, for any build, we can modify the run time `PATH` environment variable to that it finds the necessary DLLs.

In the case of a debug build, we can start the application in debug mode. That seems not to read the `PATH` set for run time.

Or, putting it another way, the application doesn't seem to find the files one directory level above (`../dir1`) when debugging.

Where can I modify the `PATH` used while starting the app in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

Left panel: click `Projects`
This opens a sub-panel with `Manage kits...`, `Active Project`,  `Build&Run` and `Project Settings`. Select `Build&Run` > `(your kit)` > `Run`.
This opens a `Run Settings` page. In `Environment`, unfold details. You can change env variables here or setup your own.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. It works if I ckick the play button of QtCreator. If I click the debug  button then the app do not find files  one directory level above.

Comment: Then it's not `PATH` you need to change but your Working Directory. That's just above `Environment`, in the same `Run Settings` page.